# Kinect For Windows Developer Toolkit V2.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm working on a project using C# and kinect v2. 
I am looking for "Kinect For Windows Developer Toolkit V2.0.0"  But still I didn't find it.

I already downloaded the SDK V1.8. and installed. It has developer toolkit, All codes are correct but kinect didn't work.

Then I downloaded SDK V2.0.0 but my project didn't work.

I think I need a developer toolkit V2.0.0 but I didn't find it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Which Kinect are you using? If its Kinect v2 then the 1,8 will definitely not work.

Also, the "Kinect For Windows Developer Toolkit (which basically had resources and samples in C#, C++ etc) was available in 1.8, and now has been renamed to SDK Browser v2.0 and contains all the samples etc for the v2 Kinect. It comes bundled with the Kinect SDK 2.0.

Comment: I'm using Kinect v2.  
Yes I installed Kinect SDK 2.0 and I added the Microsoft.Kinect.dll reference to the visual studio, but the code not work and  gives  error messages. 

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which code? What errors? I recommend you update the main question with the code you are using, and the complete problem with errors for others to see and solve...